# My 3D Cursor follows my selection cursor everywhere I click. How do I stop this?

Tags: 3d-cursor

This happens to me every now and then in different projects and I never know what causes it. Anywhere I click, my 3D Cursor and Selection Cursor both move to that point and I cannot separate the two. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try hitting `, (comma)` and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: THANK YOU.

What feature is that called anyways? The comma shortcut one. Also could you post this as an answer so I can accept the question being answered and you getting credit?

Comment: It's a `Pivot` setting - see [this link](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49839/21718) for more info on its behavior. I'm not sure if this will be considered a duplicate or not, so for now I'm not going to post as an answer.

Comment: The answers are the same, but I think because it's a different question, it might not be a duplicate. If someone is looking for information on how to set the pivot point, that other question would be more likely to come up. But I think it's reasonable to believe that someone searching for THIS problem, might not be able to tell that the other question has the answer they need. What do y'all think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Piviot Point]

You discovered the Pivot Point

This is a very useful feature in blender

Your pivot point is for example the rotation axis.

Maybe you want to rotate something around a Point then select a Vertice/Edge/Face/Object  press  Shift s to position the 3D Cursor.

Now press r and you will rotate aroud the 3D Cursor

[image: Shift + S for thiss menu]