# I need to turn one side of a cylinder into a square a leave the other side round

Tags: modeling

[image]Is it possible to make one side of a cylinder square while leaving the other alone? If so how would I go about it? I have a tree branch that I need to connect to a trunk. The number of edges on the cylindrical branch will not connect up with the square hole on my trunk...Any ideas?

Comment: do you mean a flat side?  something like this http://prntscr.com/ehmz8a ? http://prnt.sc/ehn001

Comment: The link didn't work. I added a pic.

Comment: As for other ideas, look into Bridge Edge Loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't know if this is what you wanted, but you may just *bridge* the vertices between square and circle to create this kind of shape. Add a *plane* and subdivide it as many times as you want. Then add a *circle* with the number of vertices matching the number of the vertices on the edges of the square/plane. Finally select them as pictured below, press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and type *Bridge*-->***Bridge Edge Loops***.

***NOTE:*** There is similar answer about this here on BSE, but I can't find it.

[image]

Comment: I ended up merging all of the vertices at four different points then connected those edges up. u

Answer (score 0):

To understand a little bit more of how this works in depth have a look at [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49831/erratic-apply-scale-behavior-with-vert-groups-and-displacement-modifier/49839#49839)

[image: Demo Animation]

The trick is to set your pivot mode to Active Element.

Then, select everything you would like to square off, making sure that your last element selected is the location you want your dquare edge to end up (In my case I wanted to square it off in the '-Y' Axis at the bottom edge of this cylinder).

Then, <kbd>S</kbd> >> <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> >> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Done