# How do i connect a square to a cylinder with a round like bevel?

Tags: modeling, mesh

i'm new to blender but i used to work a lot with autodesk inventor.

When i had 2 objects in inventor i could choose both edges and make a bevel or something like that between them but in blender it all works different and am i not able to get it.

I want to make this:
[image: Lemon crusher]
[image: Lemon crusher for ice tea]

And as you can see in the middle it goes from cylinder to square.

This is what i've got at the moment[image]

How do i connect them with an outer circle/bevel or how you call it?
I couldn't find a topic about this all i found where about rounding out single objects but if there is a topic about this then i would like to read it.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238803/how-can-i-model-a-bottle-with-a-solid-glass-bottom-like-this-one https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75213/i-need-to-turn-one-side-of-a-cylinder-into-a-square-a-leave-the-other-side-round

Comment: thanks ill have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create the basic shape:

[image]

Select these edges (and the ones on the opposite side) and bevel:

[image]

[image]

Bevel these other edges:

[image]

Duplicate the tip, make it circular with right click > *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

Then select the tip and the circle and right click > *LoopTools > Bridge*:

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, shade smooth:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what i ment thanks.

Comment: So this means i cant connect them together because my cyllinder has more faces then my square?

Comment: you can, but it's always better to keep the same amount of vertices on each part to get a clean topology, maybe lower down the cylinder vertices count so that it matches?

Comment: What do you mean with bevel its profile do i just apply the bevel modifier on the object or select all edges and the bevel edges?

Comment: I just selected all edges in edit mode and it kinda looks like your picture but the sides arent round just the edges are?

Comment: you don't need to use the bevel modifier, to bevel the edges, select them and Ctrl B, in the Operator box you can change some parameters. I've beveled twice: from picture 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3. Each time the bevel size was different as I needed a different width

Comment: So you just beveled the edges twice? Because what i mean is that between picture 1 and 2 a lot has changed.

Comment: I've edited to show where you're supposed to bevel, also use J (join) or K (knife) to join some vertices and keep quads

Comment: Thanks i do understand how to do it right now but for some reason blender doesnt want to cooperate.

Comment: yes im almost finished with it thanks for the multiple tips like J and K it helped me out alot when it is finished ill post a picture of it here

Comment: I kinda finished it i just need to put on a feet but the rest i have completed including the glass on top. sadly i cant show you a picture due to this post being close by some one who thought it was a duplicate. especially the K nife function came in very handy.

Comment: ok nice to hear then   ;)

Comment: yeah i thought i just noticed that i made a mistake i made the cubic part the same size as the cyllinder but it should be half as thick but now those looptools kinda find it difficult to connect them

Comment: but i fixed it by placing a cyllind with the same amount of faces under the square and bridged them it looks pretty good now