# Origin point different in editmode / objectmode

Tags: origin

*Edited due to comment by Serge L.*

I'm following a tutorial to make a worm shaft - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVTOSOKpx6I

In objectmode my object has it's origin set to the 3D cursor, which is 30cm to left on the x axis. If I rotate on Y, it rotates around the 3D cursor point - which is what I expect/want.

[image: Objectmode]

When switching to editmode however, a 3D manipulator jumps into the object like this...

[image: Editmode]

So if I try to rotate the mesh on Y, it just rotates around on it's own axis, instead of using the origin from the object/3D cursor.

If I search Manipulator 3D - I can turn it off, but the object still ignores the origin set for the object, and rotates around its own center.

Comment: Oirigin is defined by orange dot, not manipulator with axis. You should change pivot mode to 3D cursor to rotate around origin.

Comment: Rotating in Edit mode won't be done according to origin point of the object. Enable 3D cursor as pivot point and switch between Object and Edit modes to position it correctly or rotate in Object mode

Comment: Serge L - So i'll edit the post to say Manipulator with axis instead of origin, but even of I turn off the manipulator 3D - the mesh still rotates around it's own center, instead of using the 3D cursor - which is set for the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments by Serge L and Mr Zak, if you want the vertices to rotate around the origin in edit mode, you have to set the cursor to the origin (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> cursor to selected, if the object is selected) and then set the cursor as pivot point, so that every rotation and scaling will use the cursor location as pivot point.

Turning on or off the manipulators is only a visual utility, which doesn't affect the rotation behaviours.

The logic behind this is the fact that the default pivot point is the median point: in object mode you have only one object selected so the median point (pivot point) is the object origin. In edit mode you select all vertices of the mesh, and the middle point will be a location which will have the average coordinates of all vertices, and this (often empty) location will act as pivot point.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**3D Cursor Rotation Pivot**

Just hit <kbd>>.(period)</kbd> (**NOT <kbd>NUMPAD .</kbd>***) while in edit mode.

---

To switch back

**(DEFAULT) Bounding Box Center**

<kbd>,(comma)</kbd>

Comment: You may want to read [THIS ANSWER](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49831/erratic-apply-scale-behavior-with-vert-groups-and-displacement-modifier/49839#49839), it will help you understand the different pivots in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can click with your left mouse button on the object to set the 3d cursor on it, then switch to object mode, go to the tool panel on the left and click "Set Origin" and then select "Origin to 3D Cursor", otherwise you can press the spacebar (while the mouse cursor is on the 3D view) and type "set origin" to look for it. To be really precise though, you can adjust the position of the 3D Cursor in the transform panel on the right, where you can find the 3D cursor coordinates if you scroll down, then you can do the set origin procedure.
Otherwise selecting "origin to senter of mass (surface)" after pressing the "sSt Origin" button, should solve your problem too in this case.

Comment: I want the object to rotate around the 3D cursor which is about 30cm away from it's center. In object mode it rotates around it, but in editmode it rotates around it's own center. You cannot set origin in edit mode AFAIK.